# Analysis of a vintage Marantz model 18 driver circuit

Tags: amplifier

[image: Original Marantz Driver Board Schematic][image: Re-drawn schematic with drive and power output stage]

The problem with the driver circuit is that the DC balance control will not meet the required <+/- 80mV at the speaker output terminals on the left channel only. The voltages in the driver board are for the most part within acceptable limits with the exception of the collector of Q1004 which measures +11.8 V. It should be 4.

The DC balance control is at the maximum CW rotation and the output at the speakers is -340mv. For the +/-1.4 volts on the outputs of the collectors Q1006 and Q1002, they measure -1.78 and 0.74 respectively.  In trying to understand how the DC balance circuit functions I do not understand the function of the two diodes (clamping circuit) in the base circuits of Q1004 and Q1006. Since it appears that the driver circuit must provide the Q point for the power smplifier but also pass the AF signal to this stage;

How does the diode clamping circuit prevent AF distortion?

Does the AF signal path not pass through the combination of Q1004 and Q1006?

[image: Voltage Measurements from Left Channel Driver Board]

Comment: Could be anything, but have a look at R1009 and Q1003 in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

> How does the diode clamping circuit prevent AF distortion?

The diodes CR1003 and CR1004 do not prevent AF distortion. Where did you hear/read that? These diodes reduce the effects of audio overload by limiting the differential voltage to about 500mV rms.

> Does the AF signal path not pass through the combination of Q1004 and Q1006?

Yes it does.

Q1003 and Q1005 form a high gain input differential pair that feed Q1004 and Q1006 that form a lower gain differential pair. The AF signal passes to the output using the colloector of Q1006 as a currents source to the output stages.

This classic amplifier is a high power operational amplifier. It is completely dc coupled,

Q1003 is the inverting input, Q1005 is the non inverting input. From a dc perspective it is a unity-gain non-inverting configuration. R1010 and R1011 establish the ac gain.

As this is a closed loop system, a voltage discrepancy in one region will cause a voltage discrepancy elsewhere.

Two suggestions:

1. With no audio signal applied, measure the \$V_{BE}\$ of all the transistors. Should be between 0.6V and 0.68V axcept maybe the output transistors.
2. The electrolytic capacitors are getting old. I would replace them all.

Comment: I have completed measuring the voltages on all of the transistors in the Left Channel board.  I will try to get the voltages for the remaining transistors (AF power output stage) as soon as I can. The schematic I submitted with this question has some errors for some of the component values. I have attached the original Marantz schematic for clarification. 
The unit has had most of the electrolytes in the power supplies replaced and I am still in the process of replacing others. 
I have updated my original post to inclued the voltage measurements and the Marantz schematic.